# Pyspark - withColumn use googletranslate

Tags: pyspark, google-translate

I have a `name` column with different languages.
In the end, I need English.

When I use just one variable it works but how can I do this for the complete dataframe for 1 or more columns?

```
from deep_translator import GoogleTranslator
reader = "df"

NAME_ORIG = "ich suche den namen"
translated = GoogleTranslator(source='auto', target='en').translate(NAME_ORIG))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Simple approach using UDF

As suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77852450/2129801) use an [udf](https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.3.2/api/python/reference/pyspark.sql/api/pyspark.sql.functions.udf.html):

```python
from pyspark.sql import functions as F
from pyspark.sql import types as T

spark = ...

df = spark.createDataFrame([
    ['ich suche den namen'],
    ['guten tag']],
    ['name'])

@F.udf(returnType=T.StringType())
def translate(input):
    from deep_translator import GoogleTranslator
    return GoogleTranslator(source='auto', target='en').translate(input)

df.withColumn('translation', translate(F.col('name'))).show()
```

### Using mapPartitions

The udf approach creates a new `GoogleTranslator` object for each row.

The documentation of [deep-translator](https://pypi.org/project/deep-translator/#google-translate-1) says

> You can also reuse the Translator class and change/update its properties.
>
> (Notice that this is important for performance too, since instantiating new objects is expensive)

Reusing the translator object can be achieved by using [mapPartitions](https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.3.2/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.RDD.mapPartitions.html). Only one translator object per partition will be created:

```python
def translatePartition(rows):
    from deep_translator import GoogleTranslator
    dt  = GoogleTranslator(source='auto', target='en')
    for row in rows:
        yield (row['name'], dt.translate(row['name']))

df.rdd.mapPartitions(translatePartition).toDF(["name", "translation"]).show()
```

### Using mapPartitions with batches

The deep-translator api offers a [translate_batch](https://github.com/nidhaloff/deep-translator/blob/fa67ada6c5d17617628fb13447de5457a5158dc6/deep_translator/base.py#L171) function. This function can also be used by preparing the batches inside of `mapPartitions`:

```python
BATCH_SIZE=5

def translatePartitionWithBatch(rows):
    from deep_translator import GoogleTranslator
    dt  = GoogleTranslator(source='auto', target='en')
    def translateBatch(batch):
        translations  = dt.translate_batch(batch)
        for text, translation in zip(batch, translations):
            yield (text, translation)
    batch = []
    for row in rows:
        batch.append(row['name'])
        if( len(batch) >= BATCH_SIZE):
            yield from translateBatch(batch)
            batch = []
    if( len(batch) > 0 ):
        yield from translateBatch(batch)

df.rdd.mapPartitions(translatePartitionWithBatch).toDF(["name", "translation"]).show()
```

Using `GoogleTranslator.translate_batch` instead of `GoogleTranslator.translate` may or may not improve the performance further.

In all three approaches the output is the same:

```
+-------------------+------------------------+
|name               |translation             |
+-------------------+------------------------+
|ich suche den namen|I'm looking for the name|
|guten tag          |Good day                |
+-------------------+------------------------+
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create a pyspark UDF around your Google translate function, and then call that UDF in your workbook withColumn.